# Building and deployement of executable in VS 2008

Tags: visual-studio-2008

I have a text file that is used by the project and i store in Debug folder. But wen create a .exe file for the project i get an error related to file cannot be found. Please help me on this. Is it related to binaries being stored at different lcoation. I have given relative paths.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the property "Copy To Output Directory" is set to true for the text file or it will not be added to the compiled code.